# Custom CoordinatorLayout Behavior loses touch input stream after first event

Tags: java, android, touch-event, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to write a custom `Behavior` which will need to intercept touch events. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html) says that I should return true from `onInterceptTouchEvent()` to take over the event stream, then return true from `onTouchEvent()` for as long as I would like to continue receiving events. When I do this, only `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_CANCEL` events are received.

Here's how I've hooked everything up:

```java
//==============================================================================
public class CustomBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> {
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public CustomBehavior( Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) {
        super( context, attrs );
        Log.d( "AppTag", "SlidingCardBehavior" );
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent( CoordinatorLayout coordinator, View child,  MotionEvent event ) {

        Log.d( "AppTag", "onInterceptTouchEvent() "
            + MotionEvent.actionToString( event.getAction() ));

        return true;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override public boolean onTouchEvent( CoordinatorLayout coordinator, View child, MotionEvent event ) {

        Log.d( "AppTag", "onTouchEvent() "
            + MotionEvent.actionToString( event.getAction() ));

        return true;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Layout xml:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/front"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:layout_behavior="tv.shuriken.android.behavior.CustomBehavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I test this, `ACTION_DOWN` is received as expected, but no `ACTION_MOVE` or `ACTION_UP` events are. When I touch again, I immediately receive an `ACTION_CANCEL` and then another `ACTION_DOWN`.

The documentation makes it sound so simple, I'm convinced I missed something. How do I get a continuous event stream in `onTouchEvent()`?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding clickable="true" to your custom view in xml.
Also don't intercept the first ACTION_DOWN, intercept the ACTION_MOVE.